# How to separate month and year in Date in pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

This is the format of date saved in MongoDB:

```
Sun Feb 13 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How to separate month, year and day from this date in pug? I want to take this date in pug and display month and year separately.

Comment: Date values should **NEVER** be stored as strings, store always proper `Date` objects. Parsing such strings natively in MongoDB is quite difficult. I would suggest 3rd party libraries, most common are [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/parsing) and [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format)

Comment: That looks more like the format of the date displayed by a tool such as Compass.  What is the `$type` of that field in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug is built on JavaScript, so you could just use string manipulation to parse  the month, day, and year—assuming the format is consistent.

```
-
  // variable containing date string
  const myString = "Sun Feb 13 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
  // break into individual variables using destructuring
  let [dayOfWeek, month, day, year, time, timeZone, timeZoneName] = myString.split(' ')

p.postDate Posted on #{month} #{day}, #{year}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, i found a npm library called moment.js. It is super easy to use and also has many built in functions.